# There are some problems in Akka-http for java on Apache daemon

Tags: java, maven, akka, akka-http, apache-commons-daemon

I have some problems.

I tried to introduce akka-http. But I never ever develop by scala, so I used akka-http for java.

As I finished programming, I wanted to run akka-http app on Apache Daemon for product.

I tried to run on the app on linux, and use maven package. But there are some problems.

I found below messages in Daemon.out

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:145)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:172)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:246)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:315)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:683)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:245)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:288)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:233)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem.apply(ActorSystem.scala)
        at com.tet.AkkaTestMinimalHttpApp.start(AkkaTestMinimalHttpApp.java:51)
        at com.tet.DaemonLauncher.start(DaemonLauncher.java:34)
        ... 5 more
Cannot start daemon
Service exit with a return value of 5
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tet</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testapi</name>
    <description>test-api</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-http-jackson_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDK 1.8+ compatible -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons-daemon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-daemon</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-daemon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>allinone</shadedClassifierName>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>akka.Main</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is Daemon.sh

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
JSVC=/usr/bin/jsvc
USER=root

DAEMON_HOME=/home/web_admin
PID_FILE=$DAEMON_HOME/daemon.pid
OUT_FILE=$DAEMON_HOME/daemon.out
#ERR_FILE=$DAEMON_HOME/daemon.err

CLASSPATH=\
$DAEMON_HOME/test-SNAPSHOT.jar

JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"

MAIN_CLASS=com.tet.DaemonLauncher
case "$1" in
  start)
    #
    # Start Daemon
    #
    rm -f $OUT_FILE
    $JSVC \
    $JVM_ARGS \
    -user $USER \
    -java-home $JAVA_HOME \
    -pidfile $PID_FILE \
    -outfile $OUT_FILE \
    -errfile $OUT_FILE \
    -cp $CLASSPATH \
    $MAIN_CLASS
    #
    # To get a verbose JVM
    #-verbose \
    # To get a debug of jsvc.
    #-debug \
    exit $?
    ;;

  stop)
    #
    # Stop Daemon
    #
    $JSVC \
    -stop \
    -nodetach \
    -java-home $JAVA_HOME \
    -pidfile $PID_FILE \
    -outfile $OUT_FILE \
    -errfile $OUT_FILE \
    -cp $CLASSPATH \
    $MAIN_CLASS
    exit $?
    ;;

  *)
    echo "[Usage] TestDaemon.sh start | stop"
    exit 1;;
esac
```

What is my problem? I tried many things, but i failed.

Thank you.

Comment: Shade is your problem: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/general/configuration.html#when-using-jarjar-onejar-assembly-or-any-jar-bundler

Comment: I saw that. Although I used the plugin, I failed.

Comment: Have you verified that the resulting jar is correct?

Comment: yes. if i runned on only jar via command-'java -jar', it is okay.

Comment: So I assume your problem is not with Akka, it is with your launcher script?